# How can I modify a file creation time in btrfs

Tags: btrfs, timestamps, debugfs

I wanted to have snapshots on my filesystem. Since the `btrfs-convert` tool is not available anymore, I was forced to convert my filesystem by copying it file-by-file on a new file-system. However, I lost all last-status-change times in the mean time.

If I wanted to update them with extXfs, I would use debugfs, but debugfs doesn't work with btrfs. Is there a similar tool, for btrfs ?

Comment: what did you use to copy the files?   GNU cp's `-p` or `-a` options will preserve timestamps, as will `rsync`.   If you still have the original fs, it may be easier to start again....or maybe use `cp`'s `--attributes-only` option.

Comment: Well... No, Modification time is preserved (I used rsync). But not the status change time; Normally, you can't change it any other way than by changing it's status.

Comment: What do you mean by "status change time"?  Do you mean birth/creation time? That can't be changed through any normal (i.e. not a fs debugging tool or binary editor) means, it's not meant to be changeable.

Comment: Well, that's not really important but according to ls man page, `ctime` is not the creation time, but it is the time of the last modification of status information. Otherwise, of course I know that you cannot change it with normal means. That's why my question asked about some equivalent of `debugfs` for btrfs. It would also be do-able with direct editing, but then I would need know to where those fields are located on the disk.