# How to change birth/creation time without copy the whole file?

Tags: timestamps, touch

In Btrfs, `stat` a file will show birth time, which I try to change but find the method is always about copying the whole file, that would be a time waste, it'd be good to change it like access, modify, change timestamp of a file just by `touch`, can I do it as fast as `touch`?

Comment: There's nothing yet: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/693457/how-can-i-modify-a-file-creation-time-in-btrfs

Comment: That link is ambiguous. The topic title refers to "file creation time" (aka Birth Time), but the comments show that the intent was to fix up the "change time".

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I'm sorry what? *"How can I modify a file creation time in btrfs"*? Exactly the same as this question sans copying.

Comment: The linked OP's (Camion) Title says "file creation time" but his text body says "However, I lost all last-status-change times in the mean time". His following comment says "Modification time is preserved (I used rsync). But not the status change time; Normally, you can't change it any other way than by changing its status". His other comment apparently replies to "Do you mean birth/creation time? That can't be changed through any normal means" with "Well, that's not really important but ...". It seems clear to me that the title mis-states the problem being addressed.